# How to get css pseudo-element with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I try to get `color` property for the `:hover` pseudo-element, but result is no good (I get the color of the element without `:hover`).

```js
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('ok'), ':hover').getPropertyValue("color"));
```

```css
#ok {
  color: black;
}
#ok:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<p id=ok>Hello</p>
```

How to do ?

Comment: `:hover` is a pseudo-class, not a pseudo-element

Comment: @Quentin : Ok, thank you.